# Angular 4 + AdminLTE. Treeview-menu isnt working

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, adminlte

So, im working in a plataform and im using Angular 4 and AdminLTE. After logging into the dashboard, my treeview menu doesnt work. Looks like it only works at the first loading after Ng Serve, and to get it working again I need to restart my ng serve and reopen my browser.

Please help, im getting crazy with this.

(Console doesnt show me an error or something, i already Jquery installed in my project with npm install jquery, npm install @types/jquery and stuff like that)

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the admin css and js files in the angulaar-cli.json

like

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./../src/assets/css/AdminLTE.css",
    "./../src/assets/css/_all-skins.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "./../src/assets/js/adminlte.min.js"
  ],
```

and write the bellow code in the home page ngOnInit function

```
ngOnInit() {
$(document).ready(() => {
  const trees: any = $('[data-widget="tree"]');
  trees.tree();
});}
```

and the html ul should be like this

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
```